# Set border color for a chip in Android

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components, android-chips

In my android app I have a simple chip that looks like this.

[image]

Is there any way to set the color of the border to make it like this?

[image]

**UPDATE**: 
I tried to do add the shape but there's an exception during inflating the layout

```
 <android.support.design.chip.Chip
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/chip_with_border"
     android:text="my chip" />
```

`drawable/chip_with_border.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#DDDDDD"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This causes the exception

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class android.support.design.chip.Chip

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I found the answer myself. I need to add `chipStrokeColor` and `chipStrokeWidth` attributes to my `chip`

```
  <android.support.design.chip.Chip
      android:id="@+id/chip"
      style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Filter"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:chipStrokeColor="#F0F"
      app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
      android:text="my chip"
      app:checkedIcon="@drawable/ic_done_green"
      app:chipBackgroundColor="#FFF" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 15):

With the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android)  and the [**`Chip`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Chip.md) component you can use a custom style:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    style="@style/Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice"
    ..>
```

or the `app:chipStrokeColor`, `app:chipStrokeWidth`, `app:chipBackgroundColor`, `android:textColor` attributes in the xml layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
    app:chipBackgroundColor="@color/chip_background_color_selector"
    app:chipStrokeColor="@color/color_choice_chip_strokecolor_selector"
    app:chipStrokeWidth="1dp"
    android:textColor="@color/color_choice_chip_text_color"
    ..>
```

With this style:

```
  <style name="Colors_Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Choice">
    <item name="chipBackgroundColor">@color/chip_background_color_selector</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeColor">@color/color_choice_chip_strokecolor_selector</item>
    <item name="chipStrokeWidth">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_choice_chip_text_color</item>
    <item name="checkedIconVisible">true</item>
  </style>
```

For the border color you can use a **selector** to manage the different states.
Something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/primaryLightColor" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_checked="true"/>
  <!-- 87% opacity. -->
  <item android:alpha="0.87" android:color="#C6CCCD" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <!-- 38% of 87% opacity. -->
  <item android:alpha="0.33" android:color="#C6CCCD"/>

</selector>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

1- Create `shape.xml` in drawable folder and put this code inside it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#DDDDDD"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

2- then set `android:background="@drawable/shape"` attribute in your `View`

Comment: I tried to do like this but I have crash with exception `Error inflating class android.support.design.chip.Chip`

Comment: he is asking about chip border not about background